# BigQuery - Extra multiple nest child keys inside JSON document

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON structure in a field that looks like this. I'm trying to extract every **task** in every **category**, there could be any number of tasks or categories.

I've got part of the way there by extracting a single category, but can't seem to do it for every task in every category.

```
 "tasks": {
    "category-business": [
        {
            "dateCompleted": {
                "_seconds": 1653672655,
                "_nanoseconds": 791000000
            },
            "slug": "task-alpha",
            "status": "completed"
        },
        {
            "dateCompleted": {
                "_seconds": 1654516259,
                "_nanoseconds": 796000000
            },
            "slug": "task-bravo",
            "status": "completed"
        }
       ],"category-community": [
        {
            "dateCompleted": {
                "_seconds": 1654709063,
                "_nanoseconds": 474000000
            },
            "slug": "task-papa",
            "status": "completed"
        },
        {
            "dateCompleted": {
                "_seconds": 1654709841,
                "_nanoseconds": 764000000
            },
            "slug": "task-zebra",
            "status": "completed"
        }
    ]}
```

Here's the query so far

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ARRAY(
            SELECT            
                STRUCT(
                    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(
                        CAST(
                            JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(business_tasks, '$.dateCompleted._seconds') AS INT64
                        )
                    ) AS dateCompleted,
                    json_extract_scalar(business_tasks, '$.slug') AS task_slug,
                    json_extract_scalar(business_tasks, '$.status') AS status
                )
            FROM
                UNNEST(
                    json_extract_array(DATA, '$.tasks.category-business')
                ) business_tasks
        ) AS items
    FROM
        `table`
)
```

This extracts just the information in the category business.

What I'm trying to do is expand `category-community` and any other children underneath the `tasks` key. The real data has at least 10 categories and 50 tasks.

I think I need to do another round of UNNEST and json_extract_array but I can't quite work out the correct order?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function get_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";
create temp function get_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";
create temp function get_leaves(input string) returns string language js as '''
  function flattenObj(obj, parent = '', res = {}){
    for(let key in obj){
        let propName = parent ? parent + '.' + key : key;
        if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
            flattenObj(obj[key], propName, res);
        } else {
            res[propName] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
  return flattenObj(JSON.parse(input));
  ''';
create temp table temp_table as (
  select 
    split(key, '.')[offset(0)] as category, 
    split(key, '.')[offset(1)] as offset, 
    split(key, '.')[offset(2)] || ifnull(split(key, '.')[safe_offset(3)], '') as key,
    val, format('%t', t) row_id
  from your_table t, unnest([struct(get_leaves(json_extract(data, '$.tasks')) as leaves)]),
  unnest(get_keys(leaves)) key with offset
  join unnest(get_values(leaves)) val with offset using(offset)
);

execute immediate (
  select '''
    select * except(row_id) from temp_table
    pivot (any_value(val) for key in ("''' || keys || '"))'
  from (
    select string_agg(key, '","') keys 
    from (select distinct key from temp_table)
  )
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this approach works but I was looking to use this in a view I don't think I can use `create temp table` in that context?

Answer (score 1):

DML only:

```
with category_level as (
  select 
    coalesce(
      json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-business') 
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-community')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-3')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-4')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-5')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-6')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-7')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-8')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-9')
    , json_query_array(DATA.tasks[a], '$.category-10')
      ) category_array
  from table 
  left join unnest(generate_array(0, 100)) a
  where DATA.tasks[a] is not null
)

select 
  timestamp_seconds(cast(json_extract_scalar(b.dateCompleted._seconds) as int64)) dateCompleted
  , json_extract_scalar(b.slug) slug
  , json_extract_scalar(b.status) status
from category_level
left join unnest(category_array) b
```

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=1013309549723:fe8b75122e5b4b549e8081df99584c81

Answer (score 1):

new version:

```
select 
  timestamp_seconds(cast(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(json_extract(DATA,'$.tasks')), r'"_seconds":(\d*)')[offset(a)] as int64)) dateCompleted
  , regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(json_extract(DATA,'$.tasks')), r'"slug":"([a-z\-]*)"')[offset(a)] task_slug
  , regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(json_extract(DATA,'$.tasks')), r'"status":"([a-z\-]*)"')[offset(a)] status
from table
join unnest(generate_array(0,-1+array_length(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(json_extract(DATA,'$.tasks')), r'"slug":"([a-z\-]*)"')))) a
```

https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=1013309549723:9f43bd653ba14589b31a1f5673adcda7